# Book reading list for Time Series data analysis

Tags: time-series, dataset

I'm looking for book recommendations for Time series Data Analysis. All my time series data is in the engineering domain, pressure, volume, voltage, images etc.

I'm experienced in Matlab and mostly all kinds of smoothing, curve fitting, Kalman, fft type workflows but am looking for more skills specifically for feature extraction (i.e. ECG). Perhaps Wavelet, Stats?

I'm interested in learning tools but most useful would be guidance to what methods/tools to apply for a given problem. i.e. remove means, fft, band filter freq of interest, ifft, correlate and so on.